# Help! Linux server under SMTP SASLAUTHD attack!

Tags: linux, smtp

My linux sendmail server is being forced out of commission by a flood of invalid smtp saslauthd logins.
I have searched and searched for a way to determine the IP so I can block it ... no luck.
The IP is not being recorded in the messages or secure logs.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.